# Pyaudio Output Callback Stream delivers very choppy audio

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pyaudio

I am writing a program which takes audio input via Pyaudio, analyses the input via fft, extracts the dominant frequency and then generates a sin wave as a bytestring based upon the obtained frequency. All of those steps work (kinda).

However when it comes to playing the sin wave via a pyaudio callback stream, the signal gets very choppy. If i play the audio in a blocking stream however, the output sound fine.
This is the function that generates the sin wave(note that I left out quite a bit of surrounding code here):

```
self.waveData = b'' #needs to be reset here, otherwise content of this grows exponentially i guess
        for i in range(0, int(fs * 0.01)):       #make just small sample of 0.1 duration
            pcmValue = int(volume*np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*i/fs))        #i replaces self.x
            self.waveData += struct.pack('h', pcmValue)
        self.waveData+=int((duration/0.01))*self.waveData[0:len(self.waveData)]     #just multiply content of bytestring with duration/samplesize(duration/0.02)
```

So I don't think the problem lies withing here.
This is the stream and callback function (they both sit in the same class obviously):

```
def __init__(self):
        self.stream2 = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=fs, output=True,output_device_index=5,frames_per_buffer=2**13,stream_callback=self.actuallyplaystream)

def actuallyplaystream(self,in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        return (self.waveData, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

In the rest of the program I just use

```
self.stream2.start_stream()
```

and (.stop_stream()) to start the playback. As said the playback in and of it self works ok. However the choppiness in intervalls of the frames_per_buffer=2**13, setting in creating the stream. In plain english that means that, when I increase the buffer-chunksize, mentioned above, the intervalls between each 'chop' decreases and respectively increases when decreasing the chunksize.

This seems like a very easy problem to solve, however I can't seem to find the answer in any SO post or even the docs of pyaudio. I would greatly appreciate any help or even just a hint towards solving this issue.
Please don't hesitate to ask if you are confuses by the code snippets. I will figure a way out to link to all my code, if that's needed.

Thank You

(Also: if this question is inappropriate, I will immediately remove it)

Comment: Ok, so I found a way of playing audio in python without using threading at all. Also I kind of changed the scope of the program, so that I only play a wav file while checking the amplitude. Use pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound(filename),-1) to play wav files in the background. This also gives you the option to easily pause and unpause the whole channel. I don't know however if you are able to play sin waves as I intended to in the og program. Still, pygame is used together with pyaudio in the same program, which I consider to be a success.